# Is it possible to resolve a public domain in local network?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, dnsmasq

Is it possible to resolve a public domain (ex: **http://example.com/** ) in local network ?

The local network has a server which hosted a website with domain **http://example.com/**.
The local network is connected to internet

If I enter  **http://example.com/** from browser, then the request should go to local DNS and fetch my web page from my server instead of public DNS and fetch public website

Comment: did you ever heard about the hosts file?

Comment: Nothing to do you running your own DNS server (e.g. dnsmasq)

Comment: Add the following host entries to your host file and you will be able to run it in your local system.

A - IP address where website actually pointing

Comment: Ya, I configured dnsmasq as local dns and hosts files, but from devices the clients hitting public domain instead of local domain. some clients devices hitting local domain

Answer (score 2):

Usually every decently configured network has its own DNS server, which handles all of the DNS queried for attached subnet. You should configure this zone there.

So - yup, thats a common practice.

Comment: hi @drookie , I already configured, but the system has internet connection, so it is hitting public domain, when internet removed then it is hitting local domain.  I want to hit always local domain irrespective of internet connection

Comment: The trick is simple - your in-LAN machnes have to have the internal DNS as their only resolver. And this internal DNS should resolve internal resources to the internal IPs.

Comment: Ya @drookie, your are right but when I connected to Internet then its hitting public domain.  I want to use private domain which already exists in public. Without internet connection its working fine, but I want along with Internet connection